# Show that the collection $\tau^*=\{(a,b]:a,b\in \mathbb{R},a<b\}$ is a basis for a topology in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Show that the collection $\tau^*=\{(a,b]:a,b\in \mathbb{R},a<b\}$ is a basis for a topology in $\mathbb{R}$.Help me on this.Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: Well, you simply need to check if $\tau^*$ satisfies the required properties. Do you know what are the properties of a basis for some topology?

Comment: @Crostul.. Yup.  But I am confuse with the $\tau^*$. The elements are collection of half open half close intervals..

Comment: No, the elements of $\tau^*$ are not collection of intervals: the elements are the intervals. $\tau^*$ is a collection of intervals. You have to check that $$\forall (a,b] , (c,d] \in \tau^{*} , \forall x \in (a,b] \cap (c,d] , \exists (e,f] \in \tau^* | x \in (e,f] \subseteq (a,b] \cap (c,d]$$

Answer (score 0):

Think about the properties that a basis for a topology in $\mathbb{R}$ must satisfy. For the intersection, you can prove it by cases.

Comment: Can you give me a hint for the intersection? I find it hard to prove. PLEASE..I have no one to ask.. Thank you so much..

Comment: There are three possibilities for the intersection $(a,b]\cap (c,d]$, depending on how the numbers $a,b,c,d$ are ordered.